# Full Outer Join in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

The official "Google BigQuery Analytics" book indicates that BigQuery support left, right and full outer joins. I get "unrecognized" tokens errors if I try right or full outer joins though. Are these forthcoming features that are not yet supported?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official [query reference for BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins) says:

> BigQuery supports INNER, LEFT OUTER and CROSS JOIN operations.

But I do notice the book talking about `RIGHT OUTER` joins. So I'm guessing the book is talking about a forthcoming feature.

Comment: This was a case of the book trying to describe a moving target. Dremel, the underlying query engine that bigquery uses, supports FULL OUTER and RIGHT JOINS. I had thought that we could get these enabled in BigQuery more quickly. We have an open bug on this and will get to it as soon as we can.